# How could I check if the result of fitcecoc is converged

Tags: matlab, svm

When I use `fitcsvm` I could check if the result is converged or not by calling `ConvergenceInfo.Converged`.

However, if I use `fitcecoc`. How could I check if the returned `ClassificationECOC` is Converged or not?

Notice, I'm new to `matlab` and `SVM`.

Thanks

Comment: So are you using `fitcsvm` or `fitcsvm`?

Comment: Sorry ... I made a mistake ... I was using fitcsvm, But I'm trying to use fitcsvm.